# How to retrieve a List of unique String fields from a column in a table with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table with multiple lines and columns. I want to retrieve with JpaRepository a List of all the fields of a column.

Should I write a query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field2 FROM entity;
```

And annotate the method with @Query(QUERY_STRING)

or is there an easier way using JPA ?

Thank you.

Comment: These informations are not in tableName but in system table of your DBMS

Comment: Do you have an [entity class](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/types#Entity_Classes_) related to this table?

Comment: @Cepr0 Yes, I have an entity Object that have several fields field1, field2, field 3. Hibernate creates the table and I want to retrieve after a list of all the values (of duplicated) of field2.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a value list of one field you can do the following:

```java
public interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {

    @Query("select distinct e.field1 from MyEntity e")    
    List<String> getField1Values();
}
```

If you need to get a value list for many of fields I can propose you this trick with [dynamic projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic):

```java
public interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {

    // T - it's a type of a concrete projection 
    <T extends OneField> List<T> getDistinctBy(Class<T> type);

    default <T extends OneField> List<?> getFieldValues(Class<T> type) {
        return getDistinctBy(type)
               .stream()
               .map(T::getValue)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

// T - it's a type of the table field
public interface OneField<T> {
    default T getValue() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then create projections for your table fields which value list you need to get and invoke method `getFieldValues` for each projection, for example:

```java
public interface Field1 extends OneField<String> {

    @Override
    default String getValue() {
        return getField1();
    }

    String getField1();
}

List<?> values = repo.getFieldValues(Field1.class);
```

Comment: I don't want to get the field1 of MyEntity by Id. I want a list of all the field1 (without duplicated) of all the entities. To do that, I want to select only the column field1.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [JPA criteria api](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html), something akin to:

```
CriteriaQuery<Entity3450862> criteria = builder.createQuery(Entity3450862.class)
Root root = criteria.from(Entity3450862.class);
Set<Entity3450862> yourDesiredResult = new HashSet<>();
yourDesiredResult.addAll(criteria.select(root.get("T")).list());
```

should sort you. This code is untested, but should point you in the right direction.